# Convert numeric timestamp value to `MMM YYYY` format

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know how to convert data that is in timestamp into 'MMM YYYY' format in order to display the x-axis of the chart.

Here is my LineChart.vue

```
    <script>
    import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
    
    export default {
      extends: Line,
      data () {
        return {
          datacollection: {
            labels: [        <-- Timestamps
              1600934100.0,
              1602009600.0,
              1602747060.0,
              1603050158.390939,
              1603305573.992575
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: 'Data One',
                backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'white',
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointBorderColor: '#249EBF',
                data: [
                  9.0,
                  9.5,
                  2.5,
                  11.52,
                  12.4
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
    
          options: {
            lineTension: 0,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                    callback (value, index, values) {
                      return `${value }%`
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mounted () {
    
        this.renderChart(this.datacollection, this.options)
      }
    }
    </script>
```

The output that I have obtained with this code:

[image]

As you can see from the output, the x-axis is not in 'MMM YYYY' format.

I have two questions based on this:

1. How to convert the labels(which is in timestamp) into 'MMM YYYY' format, and what changes should I make in my code in order to achieve it.
2. I want to fetch data from API instead of giving the data directly, so what changes should I make in my code?

Note: My API also contains timestamps.

Here s how my API looks like:

```
     {  
        "date": [
            1600934100.0,
            1602009600.0,
            1602747060.0,
            1603050158.390939,
            1603305573.992575
        ],
    
        "challenge": [
            9.0,
            9.5,
            -2.5,
            11.52,
            12.4 
        ]
      }
```

Please help me with this as I am not able to encounter it on my own and I have been facing this for 2 weeks.

Humble request, if anyone knows the answer please do tell me by modifying my own code and sending it back, because I am new to Vuejs so wrapping the exact component or any logic becomes a problem.

Comment: Both creating a Date from a timestamp and formatting it into whatever format are simple and solved problems with tons of existing answers. You need to break up your problem into its individual parts; Vue or ChartsJS are irrelevant here. Same goes for loading the data from an API; even if ChartJS didn't support API data you could simply load the data, then pass it onto chartjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways of solving you issue. You either change the array that comes from the api into the format you want, or you do a map of your api array on the frontend side and format each date.

In my example I'll use [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/):

```
const result = [
                 1600934100.0,
                 1602009600.0,
                 1602747060.0,
                 1603050158.390939,
                 1603305573.992575
             ].map(date => DateTime.fromMillis(date * 1000).toFormat("MMM yyyy"));
```

This basically will create a new array as the following

```
 [ "Sep 2020", "Oct 2020", "Oct 2020", "Oct 2020", "Oct 2020" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may turn your numeric values into `Date` and cast that into properly formatted ([`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)) string:

```js
const src =  [1600934100,1602009600,1602747060,1603050158.390939,1603305573.992575],
             
      dates = src.map(n => 
        new Date(n*1e3)
          .toLocaleString(
            'en-US', 
            {month: 'short', year: 'numeric'}
          ))
     
console.log(dates)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```